# Bidirectional communication with RPC

Tags: go, tcp, rpc, json-rpc

I am currently implementing an RPC interface (both client and server) about some proprietary product on top of a raw TCP connection. The documentation explicitly demands a JSON-RPC communication and it also adds the following tip:

```
In <doc number>, antenna and remote device are both server and client
```

In the interface, it appears that the client should be able to receive `notifications` from the server, simple json message without the need to respond to them.

Basically, it looks like this:

```
Server ---------------------------------------------------- Client

       <------------------------ Client Initiate Connection
       Server acknowledge connection opened -------------->

       Server sends a notification about some event------->
       Server sends another notif. about another event---->

       <---------------------------- Client Stop Connection
       Server acknowledge connection stopped ------------->
```

Doing a simple request/response event is easy:

The server looks like this:

```
func (l *Listener) GetLine(line []byte, ack *bool) error {
    fmt.Println(string(line))
    return nil
}

func main() {
    addy, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "0.0.0.0:42586")
    inbound, _:= net.ListenTCP("tcp", addy)
    listener := new(Listener)
    rpc.Register(listener)
    rpc.Accept(inbound)
}
```

And the client is able to call to the server function

```
client, err := rpc.Dial("tcp", "localhost:42586")
in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
for {
    line, _, err := in.ReadLine()
    var reply bool
    client.Call("Listener.GetLine", line, &reply)
}
```

In this situation, I do not see how I can send data from the server to the client. How can I do this using the same TCP connection? How can they be both server and client ?

Comment: You'll need to a tcp conn instead of the rpc package. See https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmfYeDhGH9bZzihBUDEQbCbTc5k5FZKURMUoUvfmc27BwL/socket/tcp_sockets.html for examples.

Comment: Thanks Marc. The documentation is explicitly specifying the need to use RPC and it also says that "Antenna and remove device are both server and client". It makes very little sense to me..

Comment: Rpc is a fairly generic term. Is it talking about the Go net.rpc package specifically, or just RPC? If the latter, it doesn't actually mean anything specific.

Comment: What is the protocol you're intending to use for this proposed "bidirectional rpc"?